# is it possible to block bootstrap css from loading on a Reactjs Page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

We have a project we build where we did not use bootstrap css.  However, we realize that we now need it on only 1 of our pages to make the grids reactive.  It works fantastic for that one page, but jumbles up the elements on all of our other pages due to bootstrap overriding our styles.

Is it possible to..
- only load bootstrap css to a single React page?
- block bootstrap from loading on pages where we dont want it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try importing the bootstrap css file only in the component that it is needed in and use it via inline-styles.  Not sure though if that bleeds over into other components.  Worth a shot =)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this step by step and was easily able to EXPLICITLY use bootstrap css wherever I wanted.

Download the project they provide first and you'll see exactly how it works.  Then follow the steps and you're done.

https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap